# How to transfer multiprocessing Queue from tkinter class to worker class/functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

at the moment I can't queue.get() the values from my tkinter UI in my worker functions. The queue is filled correctly and in my tkinter class I can queue.get() successfully but nothing happens in my worker functions. Maybe you can see the problem:

```
quantity_ac4 = "1"
first_com_port = "COM4"
second_com_port = "COM9"
queue_1 = Queue()
queue_2 = Queue()


def start_ui():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("HIL")
    GUI(root, quantity_ac4, queue_1, queue_2)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ui_process = Process(target=start_ui)
    ui_process.start()

    board1_process = Process(target=Boards(first_com_port, second_com_port,
                                           quantity_ac4, queue_1, queue_2).tasks_board1)
    board1_process.start()

    board2_process = Process(target=Boards(first_com_port, second_com_port,
                                           quantity_ac4, queue_1, queue_2).tasks_board2)
    board2_process.start()


class Boards:
    def __init__(self, first_com_port, second_com_port, quantity_ac4, queue_1, queue_2):
        self.first_com_port = first_com_port
        self.second_com_port = second_com_port
        self.quantity_ac4 = quantity_ac4
        self.queue_1 = queue_1
        self.queue_2 = queue_2

    def tasks_board1(self):
        while True:

            # Execute UI instructions when values are available
            while not self.queue_1.empty():
                # sash position
                pin5_num1.write(self.queue_1.get() / 830 + 0.05)
                # temperature
                pin3_num1.write(self.queue_1.get() / 42)
                # cross slider
                pin2_num1.write(self.queue_1.get() / 2)
                # Motion detector
                pin23_num1.write(self.queue_1.get())
                # Light barrier
                pin22_num1.write(self.queue_1.get())
```

I guess the tkinter class isn't the problem but here is the basic code in it:

```
self.queue_1.put(self.sash_position_1.get())
```

Best regards

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty), `Queue.empty()` is not reliable for multithreading/multiprocessing. Moreover, `Queue.get()` is blocking by defualt. So, unless you plan to do something else other than waiting for the queue, the condition `while not queue.empty()` is redundant. Would removing the inner `while` loop help with the issue?

Comment: I have other code blocks that should run when no queue value is available. Nevertheless I removed the while not loop and now it seems that the code is stucked waiting for a queue value to get. Do I have to return the queue_1 in my tkinter code and catch it in the main code?

Comment: I have another question. You say you use both `Queue.put()` and `Queue.get()` in your tkinter code. Could you show it? Maybe you are inserting and immediately removing the objects from the queue?

Comment: It is "stuck" in the `Queue.get()` because that is how a blocking call works. There is no need to return and catch anything (I don't really know what you mean by this). If a process is blocked on a `Queue.get()`, it will continue its execution after another process does a `Queue.put()`

Comment: So normally it should continue by pressing the UI button whose callback function is filling the queue by using `queue.put()`. I deleted the `queue.get` in the tkinter code because I just wanted to check if the queue gets filled or not.

Comment: I will try to rebuild the code as short as possible and without pyfirmata maybe it'll help.